# Redshift where time between 2 times

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I want to get records between 2 times. The column is in datetime format.

Say, I want to get records between 10am and 2:30pm.

In Mysql, I can write `TIME(datetime_col)>='10:00' AND TIME(datetime_col)<='14:30'`

I am wondering the redshift equivalent of that.

I can try `extract(hour from datetime_col)` but that won't be correct as I need to consider minutes too.

I could try `to_char(datetime_col, 'HH24:MI')` but that will not compare with <= or  >=

I am wondering if there is an easy way to achieve it and I am missing it completely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think Redshift has a `time` data type.  So one option is to convert to strings:

```
TO_CHAR(datetime_col, 'HH24:MI') >= '10:00' AND 
TO_CHAR(datetime_col, 'HH24:MI') <= '14:30'
```

Comment: Damn, I tried that already but it didn't work or so I thought because it didn't have any data between those times. I knew it would work as soon as I put the question here. Thanks mate